# Does the Zealot barbarian's Rage beyond Death feature let you survive if you receive healing regardless of your death saves?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, healing, character-death, barbarian

In *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* (p. 11), the [Path of the Zealot](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#PathoftheZealot) gives a barbarian the ["Rage Beyond Death"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#RagebeyondDeath-648) feature at level 14 (emphasis mine):

> Beginning at 14th level, the divine power that fuels your rage allows
> you to shrug off fatal blows.
>
> While you’re raging, having 0 hit points doesn’t knock you
> unconscious. You still must make death saving throws, and you suffer
> the normal effects of taking damage while at 0 hit points. However, if
> you would die due to failing death saving throws, you don’t die until
> your rage ends, and **you die then only if you still have 0 hit
> points.**

RAW, this says that regardless of your death saves, if you receive healing before the end of your rage and have 1 HP, you remain alive *regardless* of the outcomes of your death saves.

Is that the case? And is that RAI?

Comment: It's generally assumed that healing above 0HP resets death save to 0 fail / 0 success, even for a Zealot because their rules don't override that: see [What happens if the Spare the Dying cantrip is cast on a Zealot barbarian using Rage Beyond Death?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/154651) where the consensus is that applies even for stabilization effects that *don't* bring you above 0 HP.  (Although arguably you're *still* at 0HP rather than *again* if you never went above 0).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Yes, it is the case.

Your reading is correct - the PC stays alive even if they fail their death saving throws (or, more generally, get 3 failures on death saving throws any way - including damage from enemies, which is most likely), if they are healed before their rage ends.

## Yes, it seems to be Rules as Intended.

The wording is very clear and explicitly states the situation:

> However, **if you would die due to failing death saving throws**, you don’t die until your rage ends, and *you die then only if you still have 0 hit points.*

If it was not intended, that *last clause* would not exist. The phrase could just end before that statement, something on the lines of:

> However, if you would die due to failing death saving throws, you don’t die until your rage ends.

## Note that, RAW, you can still die by other means.

The feature prevents death from failed death saving throws, but not any other kinds of death - for example, death from massive damage is still possible.

Comment: Noting that a L14 Barbarian will have 150 max hp or more on average so there are very few effects in the game that can kill them with massive damage.

Comment: Agreed. There aren't many things dealing 20d10 damage and then high-rolling it. But I wanted to mention it just as a clarification that the Barbarian is not immortal. Other instant death effects also work. (Like a CR2 brain-like creature eating your brain-like brain)

Comment: @HellSaint - Of note: That doesn't actually kill you until it vacates your body. And in the case of a Barbarian, it's probably a marked improvement on his intellect anyways.

Comment: @HellSaint or Power Word Kill

Comment: Or hit with disintegrate while having too low of HP to remain above 0.

Comment: Very important consideration that's been mentioned is that this does not provide immunity to effects that say "If damage from this spell reduces a target to 0 hit points...." Your barbarian had better hope that enemy wizard doesnt have Immolation prepared.

Comment: The highlight in this answers quote is weird. you refer to the last clause but highlight the center one. is there a reason for that?

Comment: @findusl Italic is being used to highlight the last sentence. That's why *last clause* is also in italic (i.e., to refer to the *italic highlighted* part)

Comment: @Hellsaint that is very unusual. Why is the other part in bold? I think if you have to explain a highlight it's not a good highlight.