# Is it possible to heal before dying as a Zealot Barbarian?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-death, barbarian, rage

I apologize if the title of this post isn't spot on, but it's a multifaceted question.  Firstly, I'm a little confused about a how Barbarian's rage functions as combat ends.  As written:

> **Your rage lasts for 1 minute**. It ends early if you are knocked unconscious or if your turn ends and you haven't attacked a hostile creature since your last turn or taken damage since then. You can also end your rage on your turn as a bonus action.

Supposing a fight ends after 5 rounds of combat, at 6 seconds per round, a raging Barbarian should, assuming the turn order is in his/her favor, have 6 seconds (1 round) before his/her rage ends, correct?  Would that be enough time to use an action?  If we then look at Persistent Rage:

> Beginning at 15th level, your rage is so fierce that it ends early only if you fall unconscious or if you choose to end it.

According to the scenario above, would this then mean that a Barbarian would have 30 seconds - regardless of whether he/she attacks or takes damage - to take some kind of action?  I'm just curious as to whether or not a Zealot Barbarian would have a chance to heal him/herself before dying.  According to Rage Beyond Death:

> While you're raging, having 0 hit points doesn't knock you unconscious. You still must make death saving throws, and you suffer the normal effects of taking damage while at 0 hit points. However, if you would die due to failing death saving throws, **you don't die until your rage ends**, and you die then only if you still have 0 hit points.

Essentially, since you don't die until your rage ends, and your rage ends after 1 minute, would a fight that doesn't go 10 rounds give a Zealot Barb a chance to heal immediately after combat?  Sorry for the long post.

Comment: Related or perhaps a partial dupe: "[Does the Zealot barbarian's Rage beyond Death feature let you survive if you receive healing regardless of your death saves?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/121661)"

Comment: Didn't see that - thanks Exempt-Medic.  Although, after reading it, I see my question is more about the timing involved.

Comment: I’ve added the [dnd-5e] tag since you are are clearly referring to dnd 5e material.

Answer (score 9):

#### You have understood all the relevant rules.

Rage states:

> It **ends early** if you are knocked unconscious or if your turn ends and you haven't attacked a hostile creature since your last turn or taken damage since then.

This is what Persistent Rage is talking about when it says:

> Beginning at 15th level, your rage is so fierce that it **ends early** only if you fall unconscious or if you choose to end it.

When the fight ends, in your scenario, you have 30 seconds before your rage ends, because your rage cannot end early unless you choose to do so. It then follows that you may receive healing in those 30 seconds, and you will not die when your rage ends.